# How to open firefox window in fullscreen by default

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

My POS system is set to open in firefox as defult page. So it would be nice if I could open it in full screen by default.

So Can I know, Is there any way to make the firefox window open in full screen by default?

I know that Firefox can expand to fill my entire screen with its Full Screen feature by togglling Full Screen keyboard shortcut of F11 key. But just I want to enable that feature by default.

Any suggestions on how to revert to full screen by default would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox now has a "kiosk" mode

```
firefox --kiosk
```